# css and js files not properly carry on custom theme in Drupal 8

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I'm having a problem because my CSS's and JS's not load properly. I tried various forms and ways, followed countless tutorials and always get the same result.

My css and js files are loaded like this:

```
/drupal/themes/mytheme/0?ofeszb
```

with a number instead of name and without the CSS extension, and charges that the file does not exist.

my info file:

```
name: My Site Name
description : Site personalizado
type: theme
core: 8.x
libraries:
  - mytheme/global-css
  - mytheme/global-js
regions:
  header: 'Header'
  content: 'Content'
  footer: 'Footer'
```

my libraries file:

```
global-css:
  css:
    theme:
      - css/style.css: {}
global-js:
  js:
    - js/main.js: {}
```

my page.html.twig file:

```
<div id="head">{{page.header}}</div>

<div id="content">{{page.content}}</div>

<div id="footer">{{page.footer}}</div>
```

Comment: get rid of the `-` here `- css/style.css: {}` and here `- js/main.js: {}`

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly now. Wow, I do not know how I missed this!